# Changing background paper

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, backgrounds

I’ve written this paper using tcolorbox with a coloured background. I want to use a background like in the  image below.Can someone give a hand. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
 \usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;} 
\definecolor{anti-flashwhite}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.96}
\definecolor{antiquewhite}{rgb}{0.98, 0.92, 0.84}
\definecolor{beige}{rgb}{0.96, 0.96, 0.86}
\definecolor{burlywood}{rgb}{0.87, 0.72, 0.53}
\definecolor{capri}{rgb}{0.0, 0.75, 1.0}
\begin{document}
\
\pagecolor{beige}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=Nombres Rationnels,attach boxed title to top center=
{yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},boxed title style={size=small,colback=burlywood}]

Les nombres rationnels sont les nombres de la forme $r=\dfrac{a}{b}$ où est $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ et $b\in\mathbb{N}^*$. Il existe une infinité de manière d'écrire un nombre rationnel, par exemple: 
\\
$\dfrac12=\dfrac24=\dfrac48=\cdots$ Cependant, on conviendra d'identifier un rationnel $r$ par son représentant irréductible correspondant à la fraction irréductible $\dfrac{a}{b}$.
\\

Un nombre $r$ est un rationnel si et seulement si sa partie décimale est finie ou illimitée et périodique.\\
Par exemple: $0.25; \, 0.6666\cdots;\, 1.313131\cdots$ sont des rationels.
En effet:\\
$0.25=\dfrac{25}{100}=\dfrac{25}{25\times4}=\dfrac{1}{4}$.
\\
de même si $x=0.666\cdots$ alors $10x=6.666\cdots=6+0.666\cdots$ de sorte que: $10x=6+x$ et donc $9x=6$ ou plus simplement $x=\dfrac23\in\mathbb{Q}$
\\
\boxed{\textbf{Exercice}}: Ecris $1.313131\cdots$ sous sa forme irréductible.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=Propriétés de Nombres Réels ,attach boxed title to top center=
{yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},boxed title style={size=small,colback=burlywood}]

\checkmark\quad Si $a$ et $b$ sont deux nombres réels alors $ab=0$ est équivalent à $a=0$ ou $b=0$.
\\Par exemple si $(2x-1)(x-\pi)=0$ alors $2x-1=0$ ou bien $x-\pi=0$, 
\\soit: $x=\dfrac12$ ou bien $x=\pi$.
\\
Si $a,b,c$ et $d$ sont quatre réels tels que $b$ et $d$ soient non nuls alors:\\
\checkmark\quad $\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{c}{d}$ est équivalent à $ad=bc$\\
\checkmark\quad $\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{c}{b}=\dfrac{a+c}{b}$\\
\checkmark\quad $\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{c}{d}=\dfrac{ad+bc}{bd}$\\
\checkmark\quad $\dfrac{a}{b}\times\dfrac{c}{d}=\dfrac{ac}{bd}$\\
\checkmark\quad Si de plus $c$ et $d$ sont non nuls alors: $\dfrac{{\dfrac{a}{b}}}{\dfrac{c}{d}}=\dfrac{a}{b}\times\dfrac{c}{d}$
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=Nombres Proportiennels ,attach boxed title to top center=
{yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},boxed title style={size=small,colback=burlywood}]
Soient $a,b,c$ et $d$ quatres nombres réels.
\\
\checkmark\quad $a$ et $c$ sont proportionnels à $b$ et $d$ signifie que: $\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{c}{d}$
\\ \checkmark\quad $a$ $c$ sont inversement proportionnels à $b$ et $d$ signifie que: $ad=bc$.
\\
\tcbset{colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black}
\begin{tcolorbox}[top=0mm]
\textbf{Exercice}:
Montrer que si $\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{c}{d}$ alors $\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{a+c}{b+d}=\dfrac{3a+4c}{3b+4d}$ lorsque ces quantités sont définies.
\tcbset{colback=green!5!white,colframe=green!75!green}
\tcblower
\textbf{Corrigé}: On pose $k=\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{c}{d}$, alors $a=kb$ et $c=kd$ de sorte que: $a+c=kb+kd=k(b+d)$ et donc $k=\dfrac{a+c}{b+d}$. Inspire toi de ce qui précède et montre l'égalité suivante.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may get mad at me but please don't. However, I really feel that you will greatly benefit from cleaning up your code. `\usepackage{fullpage}` followed by `\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}`? What of your code is relevant to your question?

Comment: I wont get mad. Just a latex beginner.

Comment: We are all beginners. You are loading a lot of things that are not needed to run the code, and this frightens some of those who could help off.

Comment: I load things I thought that might help for things coming next into the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am focussing on the background. Nevertheless, I do not know how good an idea it is to nest `tcolorbox`es and to use `\def` to overwrite `\checkmark`. However, the following does not depend on this.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;} 
% I would not overwrite a standard command
\definecolor{anti-flashwhite}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.96}
\definecolor{antiquewhite}{rgb}{0.98, 0.92, 0.84}
\definecolor{beige}{rgb}{0.96, 0.96, 0.86}
\definecolor{burlywood}{rgb}{0.87, 0.72, 0.53}
\definecolor{capri}{rgb}{0.0, 0.75, 1.0}
\definecolor{bgblue}{RGB}{197,219,229}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \fill[bgblue] (current page.north east) rectangle ++(-0.8,-8.8);
 \foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 1]in {1, 3/2, 11/6, 25/12, 137/60, 49/20, 363/140, 
 761/280, 7129/2520, 7381/2520}
 {\fill[bgblue] ([yshift={-8.1cm-2*\X*1cm}]current page.north east) 
 rectangle ++(-0.8,1/\Y);}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{beige}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=Nombres Rationnels,attach boxed title to top center=
{yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},boxed title style={size=small,colback=burlywood}]

Les nombres rationnels sont les nombres de la forme $r=\dfrac{a}{b}$ où est $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ et $b\in\mathbb{N}^*$. Il existe une infinité de manière d'écrire un nombre rationnel, par exemple: 
\\
$\dfrac12=\dfrac24=\dfrac48=\cdots$ Cependant, on conviendra d'identifier un rationnel $r$ par son représentant irréductible correspondant à la fraction irréductible $\dfrac{a}{b}$.
\\

Un nombre $r$ est un rationnel si et seulement si sa partie décimale est finie ou illimitée et périodique.\\
Par exemple: $0.25; \, 0.6666\cdots;\, 1.313131\cdots$ sont des rationels.
En effet:\\
$0.25=\dfrac{25}{100}=\dfrac{25}{25\times4}=\dfrac{1}{4}$.
\\
de même si $x=0.666\cdots$ alors $10x=6.666\cdots=6+0.666\cdots$ de sorte que: $10x=6+x$ et donc $9x=6$ ou plus simplement $x=\dfrac23\in\mathbb{Q}$
\\
\boxed{\textbf{Exercice}}: Ecris $1.313131\cdots$ sous sa forme irréductible.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=Propriétés de Nombres Réels ,attach boxed title to top center=
{yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},boxed title style={size=small,colback=burlywood}]

\checkmark\quad Si $a$ et $b$ sont deux nombres réels alors $ab=0$ est équivalent à $a=0$ ou $b=0$.
\\Par exemple si $(2x-1)(x-\pi)=0$ alors $2x-1=0$ ou bien $x-\pi=0$, 
\\soit: $x=\dfrac12$ ou bien $x=\pi$.
\\
Si $a,b,c$ et $d$ sont quatre réels tels que $b$ et $d$ soient non nuls alors:\\
\checkmark\quad $\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{c}{d}$ est équivalent à $ad=bc$\\
\checkmark\quad $\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{c}{b}=\dfrac{a+c}{b}$\\
\checkmark\quad $\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{c}{d}=\dfrac{ad+bc}{bd}$\\
\checkmark\quad $\dfrac{a}{b}\times\dfrac{c}{d}=\dfrac{ac}{bd}$\\
\checkmark\quad Si de plus $c$ et $d$ sont non nuls alors: $\dfrac{{\dfrac{a}{b}}}{\dfrac{c}{d}}=\dfrac{a}{b}\times\dfrac{c}{d}$
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=Nombres Proportiennels ,attach boxed title to top center=
{yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},boxed title style={size=small,colback=burlywood}]
Soient $a,b,c$ et $d$ quatres nombres réels.
\\
\checkmark\quad $a$ et $c$ sont proportionnels à $b$ et $d$ signifie que: $\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{c}{d}$
\\ \checkmark\quad $a$ $c$ sont inversement proportionnels à $b$ et $d$ signifie que: $ad=bc$.
\\
\tcbset{colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black}
\begin{tcolorbox}[top=0mm]
\textbf{Exercice}:
Montrer que si $\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{c}{d}$ alors $\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{a+c}{b+d}=\dfrac{3a+4c}{3b+4d}$ lorsque ces quantités sont définies.
\tcbset{colback=green!5!white,colframe=green!75!green}
\tcblower
\textbf{Corrigé}: On pose $k=\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{c}{d}$, alors $a=kb$ et $c=kd$ de sorte que: $a+c=kb+kd=k(b+d)$ et donc $k=\dfrac{a+c}{b+d}$. Inspire toi de ce qui précède et montre l'égalité suivante.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. What about the page numerotation and the chapetering?

Comment: @HAMIDINESOUMARE Your question was on the background, right?

Comment: yes it was about the background. By the way your help will be appreciated for the page numerotation at if possible the chaptering. Again thank you